# Which value of a cell is retained If I give two arguments for it?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

First I had filled with D2 value as B2*5 , Then I got the output as 10 since the value
in my B2 cell was 2
Then I created a command button and the code i written for the button was 
Range("D2").Value=4
My doubt is the value of D2 cell is 4 after clicking the button, Why don't it retain the 
previous value of D2 as 10 (since B2 is still 2 and D2 is still B2*5) or it gives an 
error?

Comment: "`since B2 is still 2 and D2 is still B2*5`" no. If you are declaring the value of D2 via `Range("D2").Value=4` then D2 will be 4. I don't understand what you are trying to do here, you have declared the value as D2 to be 4 via vba, but want it to remain as `=B2*5`?

Comment: my problem is why it does not pop up an error stating that you had already declared D2 as B2*5 , so you cannot click the button and change the value of D2 to something else........Anyways I am fine this , I just wanted to know

Comment: Because you haven't told it to pop up an error.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments you haven't told it to throw up an error. You can check if the cell is blank before over writing it.

```
If Range("D2") = "" Then
    Range("D2") = 4
Else
    MsgBox ("This cell already contains a formula")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

After you run:

```
Range("D2").Value=4
```

the formula that you originally placed in **D2** has been erased and replaced by a constant.